# What Qt type do I need to use to pass a lambda as a function argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, qt5

Now that Qt5 supports connecting signals to lambda functions, I would like to be able to pass a lambda as an argument to another function. I've got a function that looks something like this:

```
void SomeFunc(Functor f)
{
    connect(obj, &MyObject::someSignal, f);
}
```

However, the compiler complains when I do that:

```
"Functor" has not been declared
```

Changing `Functor` to `QtPrivate::Functor` yields:

```
QtPrivate::Functor is not a type
```

Basically, all I want to do is pass the argument that `QObject::connect` is going to get to my function. What type do I need to use?

Comment: I haven't used it, but one thing I am certain. The type would be a template parametrized with the return and argument types. I would probably just use C++11's `std::function`, though Qt will probably have it's own type for it too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two options:

```
template<typename Functor>
void SomeFunc(Functor f)
{
    connect(obj, &MyObject::someSignal, f);
}
```

or

```
void SomeFunc(std::function<void(/*ArgumentTypes...*/)> f)
{
    connect(obj, &MyObject::someSignal, f);
}
```

The first option simply forwards any argument to the `connect`, the second uses polymorphic function pointer from C++11 standard library. It's template argument must correspond to the signature of the signal. Qt signals are void, the /*ArgumentTypes...*/ need to be replaced by the list of arguments of the function. So if the signal is declared as

```
void someSignal(int, QString);
```

the function will be

```
std::function<void(int, QString)>
```